# How do I get rid of this annoying pop up on Windows 10 (Chrome browser)

Tags: anti-virus, malware

Apologies if this is the wrong group.  I did look for a "Ask Differerent" group that is for Windows user rather than Mac users, to no avail.  If there's a better group, please point me that way.

How do I get rid of the annoying Chrome window that comes up periodically.  It might happen on Edge and Explorer too, but I use Chrome 95% of the time.  I did some research that suggested it was browser independent and to try Malware.  I did so, without luck.

[image]

A little research reveals that if you call the number, they will ask you for remote access to to your computer and "fix" the problem for a small fee.  Probably not the best solution :).  I'm using AVG virus protection (free version) if that is relevant.

I'm assumming there is some sort of program to look for in Add/Remove programs or a registry setting to modify, but I've had no luck so far.
Thanks, Dave

Comment: [su] is probably the best place.

Comment: It IS malware. Use anti-malware tools to remove it or reinstall the OS and be careful when using it.

Comment: You don’t, it’s JavaScript, from a malicious website.  Security software can prevent you from visiting hosts known to serve malicious content.  AVG software will not prevent you adequate protection.